Prove that $\{a^nb^nc^m\mid n \leq m\}$ is not context-free, using only closure properties
We can use the pumping lemma to prove that $\{a^nb^nc^m \mid n \leq m\}$ is not a context-free language. It turns out that the proof is very similar to the proof for the more famous $\{a^nb^nc^n \mid n \geq 0 \}$. So I wonder: is it possible to prove that $\{a^nb^nc^m \mid n \leq m\}$ is not context-free using only closure properties and the fact that $\{a^nb^nc^n \mid n \geq 0 \}$ is not context-free?
This is a follow-up to a similar question about showing $a^nb^m$ is not regular. We could solve that problem by intersecting with the reverse of the language, but that trick won't work here because CFLs are not closed by intersection.

I see how to prove the opposite implication using closure properties, but unfortunately, I do not see a proof for your question.
